# Remembering display screen size

Tags: display

Ubuntu 18.10, Gateway DX4300, Dell monitor. (lshw attached)

I recently installed a widescreen monitor.  Now, if the computer goes to powersave, it looses knowledge of the aspect ratio and gives me a 3x4 display with the correct height but shortened width.

How can I make the OS remember the correct display size.

---

LSHW: (edited)

```
biskithome  
    description: Desktop Computer  
    product: DX4300 (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)  
    vendor: Gateway
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Gateway Desktop frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=90FBA62A-022B-2009-1129-202403000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: RS780
       vendor: Gateway
       physical id: 0
       `BIG SNIP`
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 10
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
          `BIG SNIP`
        *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: RS780 Host Bridge
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
          `BIG SNIP`
        *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:26 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:c800(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
`TRUNCATED`
```